# How to update next-intl to 2.14.4

Tags: next.js13, next-intl

I have currently `next-intl 2.13.0-beta.2` installed.

I have tried to update it to 2.14.4 with `npm install next-intl@latest`

But `import { getTranslations } from 'next-intl/server'` not working. I got the error `getTranslation` is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies, I think there was some confusion in regard to the versioning. If you use RSC features, you should stay on the beta channel for now, the latest version is `next-intl@2.15.0-beta.5` (see [docs](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/next-13/server-components))

Here's a bit more context: https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/issues/286.